# Use Entity persisted ID in another property's value in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fullcalendar, entity, listener

Hello I use FullCalendar and I want to put an url on my event so that when I click on it I get another page with its ID, the problem is I don't know how to put the object's Id on the url.
I saw the `postPersist` method but it doesn't work.

I wrote it in my EntityListener and this returns me an error :

> "App\EntityListener\PlanningUrl::postPersist(): Argument #1 ($args)
> must be of type Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs,
> App\Entity\Cda given"

```
/** @PostPersist */
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();

    if (!$entity instanceof Cda) {
        return;
    }

    $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
    $entity->setUrl('cda/'.$entity->getId());
    $entityManager->persist($entity);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

Comment: Have you included `use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;` at the top of your listener/subscriber?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.